# Android - ensuring assets are sharp on multiple devices

Tags: android

I am testing my app on two devices and I am currently trying to understand how the drawables folders work:

- Galaxy S2
- Nexus 7

The logos are both being picked up from the `hdpi` folder eg: `res/drawable-hdpi` and I believe this is because they have the following densities.

- Galaxy S2 - 219
- Nexus 7   - 216

Which relate to Google's density range and are indeed `hdpi`:

[image]

If you look at the two screenshots for my app homescreen logo:

**Galaxy S2**

[image]

**Nexus 7**

[image]

You can see the logo on the Nexus 7 is a bit blurry, how can I provide a different asset for a 7" tablet if it comes from the same resource drawables folder? Do I need to set some size on the logo somewhere?

I have also read that the Nexus 7 is also categorized as `tvdpi` but I'm not sure I should be creating any folder for that or not.

Comment: What is the size of your picture (in pixels)? And how is it integrated into layout (wrap_content/fill_parent) ?

Comment: 375px width and height transparent png

Comment: <ImageView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:src="@drawable/flyxc_logo"
      android:tileMode="repeat" />

Comment: I don't understand this. Nexus 7 width is 800px, so your image should be repeated at least twice (and third tile should not be full). Why is it centered?

Comment: Ok this is because there is about 110px transparent either side, I have changed the tileMode to default. Any other thoughts on the quality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If both devices have about the same density, it means the size of the image widget which shows the logo is dependent on the screen size, because the size of the logo is larger on the larger screen. This could be the reason why it looks pixelated. So first make sure the image is not stretched.

You can provide alternative resources for various screen sizes. See for example "smallestWidth" in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html
So if you have to do it, you can add a new image with the same name as your logo image in `resources/drawable-sw500dp-hdpi/`. I picked 500 because 800 / 1.5 = 533.

Comment: This. Google recommends to employ swXXXdp now as the main way to manage you layout & drawables.

Comment: @aleb: the Nexus 7 is tvdpi so the math would be 800 / 1.33 = 600

Comment: @aleb indeed looks like the imageview is stretched, could be useful to look at the whole xml layout file.

Answer (score 3):

You should create a `drawable-tvdpi` folder and put any images that aren't rescaling cleanly enough in it.  Android will try to scale down your hdpi images but that does not always look nice.  I always create all images at hdpi then only recreate images for tvdpi that are scaling poorly.

That said, your image is being stretched.  Change your `ImageView` to have a height and width of `wrap_content`.

In addition... if you want to target resources to the 7" tablet, what abel said below of using `-swXXX` is the new standard way of handling it.  Unfortunately `-swXXX` was introduced in Android 3.2.. meaning the #1 7" tablet, the Kindle Fire would not see the contents of that folder.  For the moment I am still leaning on `-large` but looking forward to a time when `-swXXX` is the norm.

Comment: also it does pick up the asset from the tvdpi folder, but I just found out its discouraged according to Ms Hackborn at Google - https://plus.google.com/105051985738280261832/posts/6eWwQvFGLV8

Comment: Yeah, I think some of the discouragement from using the tvdpi folder was to limit the initial reaction to the fact that they added a new density.  Android is also quite good and rescaling images.  drawables to be careful with are iconography with thin lines.. sometimes when they get scaled down they look janky.

Comment: I think you are right, check the table - Screen pixel density (dpi) section, it does state that tvdpi is an option, and also at the formula you mentioned  1.33*mdpi. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Comment: good point on the fire, I'll probably provide swXXX and large